# How to convert bearer token into authentication cookie for MVC app

Tags: c#, owin, openid, identityserver3, bearer-token

I have a 3 tier application structure. There is a cordova js application for end-users, an implementation of identityserver3 which serves as the OpenID authority, and an MVC app which will be access through an in-app browser in the cordova application.

The starting entry point for users is the cordova app. They login there via an in-app browser and can then access application features or click a link to open the in-app browser and visit the MVC app.

Our strategy for securing the MVC website was to use bearer token authentication, since we already logged in once from the app and didn't want to prompt the user to login again when they were directed to the MVC app:

```
app.Map("/account", account =>
{
    account.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        Authority = "https://localhost:44333/core",
        RequiredScopes = new string[] { "scope" },
        DelayLoadMetadata = true,
        TokenProvider = new QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider(),
        ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint, 
    });
}
```

Since persisting the access_token on the query string is painful, I implemented a custom OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider:

```
public class QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider));
    public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        logger.Debug($"Searching for query-string bearer token for authorization on request {context.Request.Path}");

        string value = GetAccessTokenFromQueryString(context.Request);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            context.Token = value;
            //Save the token as a cookie so the URLs doesn't need to continue passing the access_token
            SaveAccessTokenToCookie(context.Request, context.Response, value);
        }
        else
        {
            //Check for the cookie
            value = GetAccessTokenFromCookie(context.Request);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                context.Token = value;
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
    [cookie access methods not very interesting]
}
```

This works, and allows the MVC application to not have to persist the access token into every request, but storing the access token as just a generic cookie seems wrong.

What I'd really like to do instead is use the access token to work with the OpenID endpoint and issue a forms-auth style cookie, which responds to logout. I found that I can add `account.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(..)` but if I authenticate via access_token, the OpenIdConnectAuthentication bits are simply skipped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't -- access tokens are designed to be used to call web apis. You use the id_token from OIDC to authenticate the user and from the claims inside you issue your local authentication cookie. The Microsoft OpenIdConnect authentication middleware will do most of this heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Is there a hook somewhere where I can inject that logic? The BearerTokenAuth bit doesn't have any callbacks and the Notifications provided in "UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication" don't seem appropriate. Perhaps an Authentication filter attribute?

Comment: The UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication MW issues the cookie for you. If you need to change the claims issued in the cookie, then handle the SecurityTokenValidated event.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Brock, If I understand correctly, I should remove the Bearer auth config entirely and replace it with UseOpenIDConnectAuthentication. In there, I'll look at the query string, pull out the token and then authorize with OIDC, deal with the ClaimsIdentity and set an Authentication Ticket. Alternatively, if I keep both Authentication things in there, I'd need to have a way to chain them, but it seems when I have a BearerToken, the other auth routine is skipped entirely.

Comment: No, you don't have to do all of that -- the OIDC MW does it for you. I'd suggest reading up on the MSFT docs on the Katana OIDC MW, or just read the code itself.